# Derivative of inverse function

Tags: calculus

A function $y=f(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$. Therefore it is also continuous at $x_0$. Suppose the function is invertible, then the derivative of the inverse function at $y_0 = f(x_0)$ is $1/f'(x_0)$. My question is except invertibility, do we need other assumptions for the above to hold? For example, $f(x)$ be continuous in a neighborhood of $x_0$? Thanks!

Comment: If $f(x)$ is not continuous in the neighborhood of $x_0$, how would you calculate $f'(x_0)$ and therefore the derivative of the inverse?

Comment: Dear Draks, the function need not be continuous in the neighborhood of $x_0$ for it to be differentiable at $x_0$. An example is the function, $f(x)=n/(n^2+1)$ for natural number $n$ and $f(x)=x$ otherwise. The function is differentiable (and therefore continuous) at $x=0$. But it is not continuous in every neighborhood of $x=0$.